# rake task in cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, rakefile

I have a shell script (`/home/user/send_report.sh`) that runs my rake task:

```
cd /home/user/rails/app
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake report:send
```

When I run it in console `sh /home/user/send_report.sh` it works properly.

I am trying to make a cron task with my script: `*/10 * * * * sh /home/user/send_report.sh`, but nothing happens! Rake task should send mail, but this does not happen.

Content of `/var/log/cron.log`:

```
Jun  2 21:40:01 ubuntu CRON[1253]: (user) CMD (sh /home/user/send_report.sh)
Jun  2 21:40:01 ubuntu CRON[1251]: (user) MAIL (mailed 240 bytes of output but got status 0x0001#012)
```

Please, help me to get the working rake script with crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that RVM single-user installation doesn't supports cron tasks. Installed RVM as multi-user and crontab worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you should use /bin/sh, i don't see anything wrong on the cron job. When you run manually, you get the email as you said right ? It does not only work when you do it with cron ? It seems that it could be a misconfiguration of the email server or maybe that the mail server port is blocked ?